# firebase type error Cannot read properties of undefined appVerificationDisabledForTesting and verify what is wrong in my code i'm getting this error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

this is my code for generating otp:

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Layout from "./../../components/Layout/Layout";
import toast from "react-hot-toast";
import OtpInput from "otp-input-react";
import PhoneInput from "react-phone-input-2";
import "react-phone-input-2/lib/style.css";
import { RecaptchaVerifier, signInWithPhoneNumber } from "firebase/auth";
import { Auth } from "../../firebase-config";

const ForgotPassword = () => {
  const [phone, setPhone] = useState("");
  const [otp, setOtp] = useState("");
  const [showOtpInterface, setShowOtpInterface] = useState(false);

  const onCaptchVerify = () => {
    try {
      // Create a new RecaptchaVerifier
      if (!window.recaptchaVerifier) {
        window.recaptchaVerifier = new RecaptchaVerifier(
          "recaptcha-container",
          {
            size: "invisible",
            callback: (response) => {
              onSignUp();
            },
            "expired-callback": () => {
              // Handle expiration if needed
            },
          },
          Auth
        );
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };

  const onSignUp = () => {
    onCaptchVerify();
    const appVerifier = window.recaptchaVerifier;
    const formatStr = `+${phone}`;

    signInWithPhoneNumber(Auth, formatStr, appVerifier)
      .then((confirmationResult) => {
        window.confirmationResult = confirmationResult;
        setShowOtpInterface(true);
        toast.success("OTP sent successfully");
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        toast.error("OTP sent failed");
        console.log(error);
      });
  };

  const onOtpVerify = () => {
    window.confirmationResult
      .confirm(otp)
      .then(async (res) => {
        console.log(res);
      })
      .catch((e) => {
        console.log(e);
      });
  };

  return (
    <Layout title={"Forgot Password - Ecommerce APP"}>
      <div className="form-container">
        <div>
          <h4 className="title">RESET PASSWORD</h4>
          <div id="recaptcha-container"></div>
          {showOtpInterface ? (
            <>
              <label htmlFor="ph">Enter Your OTP</label>
              <OtpInput
                OTPLength={6}
                otpType="number"
                disabled={false}
                autoFocus
                value={otp}
                onChange={setOtp}
              />
              <button
                type="submit"
                className="btn btn-primary mt-3"
                onClick={onOtpVerify}
              >
                Verify
              </button>
            </>
          ) : (
            <>
              <label htmlFor="email">Enter your registered phone number</label>
              <PhoneInput country={"in"} value={phone} onChange={setPhone} />
              <button
                type="submit"
                onClick={onSignUp}
                className="btn btn-primary mt-3"
              >
                Continue
              </button>
            </>
          )}
        </div>
      </div>
    </Layout>
  );
};

export default ForgotPassword;
```

**Error Details:**
I'm specifically struggling with the RecaptchaVerifier and appVerificationDisabledForTesting property. The error suggests that the properties are undefined, even though they should be accessible according to the Firebase documentation.
and error looks like this:

```
    at _verifyPhoneNumber (phone.ts:186:1)
    at signInWithPhoneNumber (phone.ts:108:1)
    at onSignUp (ForgotPasssword.js:43:1)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:4164:1)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:4213:1)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:4277:1)
    at invokeGuardedCallbackAndCatchFirstError (react-dom.development.js:4291:1)
    at executeDispatch (react-dom.development.js:9041:1)
    at processDispatchQueueItemsInOrder (react-dom.development.js:9073:1)
    at processDispatchQueue (react-dom.development.js:9086:1)
    at dispatchEventsForPlugins (react-dom.development.js:9097:1)
    at react-dom.development.js:9288:1
    at batchedUpdates$1 (react-dom.development.js:26140:1)
    at batchedUpdates (react-dom.development.js:3991:1)
    at dispatchEventForPluginEventSystem (react-dom.development.js:9287:1)
    at dispatchEventWithEnableCapturePhaseSelectiveHydrationWithoutDiscreteEventReplay (react-dom.development.js:6465:1)
    at dispatchEvent (react-dom.development.js:6457:1)
    at dispatchDiscreteEvent (react-dom.development.js:6430:1)

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'appVerificationDisabledForTesting')
    at new RecaptchaVerifier (recaptcha_verifier.ts:114:1)
    at onCaptchVerify (ForgotPasssword.js:19:1)
    at onSignUp (ForgotPasssword.js:39:1)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:4164:1)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:4213:1)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:4277:1)
    at invokeGuardedCallbackAndCatchFirstError (react-dom.development.js:4291:1)
    at executeDispatch (react-dom.development.js:9041:1)
    at processDispatchQueueItemsInOrder (react-dom.development.js:9073:1)
    at processDispatchQueue (react-dom.development.js:9086:1)
    at dispatchEventsForPlugins (react-dom.development.js:9097:1)
    at react-dom.development.js:9288:1
    at batchedUpdates$1 (react-dom.development.js:26140:1)
    at batchedUpdates (react-dom.development.js:3991:1)
    at dispatchEventForPluginEventSystem (react-dom.development.js:9287:1)
    at dispatchEventWithEnableCapturePhaseSelectiveHydrationWithoutDiscreteEventReplay (react-dom.development.js:6465:1)
    at dispatchEvent (react-dom.development.js:6457:1)
    at dispatchDiscreteEvent (react-dom.development.js:6430:1)
```

im using `"firebase": "^10.6.0",`

Request for Help:
I'm reaching out to the community for any insights or suggestions on resolving this issue. If anyone has encountered similar problems with Firebase Phone Authentication or has expertise in troubleshooting such errors, your assistance would be highly appreciated!

Comment: The error does not mean that the *property* is `undefined`, it means that you are trying to access the property from an `undefined` object reference.

Comment: The error message is trying to tell you which line of code is causing the problem. Which line is that, and what do you think is undefined in this case?